# passport Spotify strategy cors issue

Tags: node.js, passport.js, backend, spotify

So i tried to make my first request with passport set up, im being blocked by cors even if i set up my dashboard and my cors options are correctly done.
Also none of my console.logs are showing up even if i can see the requests sent from the front end like in 3rd pic. (this by using the chrome plugin to bypass cors)
[passportSetUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnrSO.png)

[auth function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlhfl.png)

[cors bypassed with chrome plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWGo7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using an a tag instead of making the actual fetch request.
example :

```
<a href="link to my backend route" </a>
```

In this way the href will make a get request to that link!